# Passing props into template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I pass `props` into a component in the markdown/template syntax?

Can I do something like React `<component :props="myObject"`>? and how would I handle that inside my component? Do props have to be declared inside my component also or can I have "unknown" set of props?

My instinct, React influenced, would do:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="Form" :prop="{title: 'foo', subTitle: 'bar'}"></component>
    </div>
</template>
```

and in my `Form.vue` file I would have not have to declare `props`, and would declare data like:

```
data(){
    return {title: '', subTitle: ''};
}
```

Comment: They (props) have to be declared inside the component.

Comment: Also, if you are using property binding :prop='some' you can have it in the data properties. Is your question passing props to a component in general or passing props to a dynamic component because `<component>` ?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I want to pass props dynamically to a `<component>`, I'm using a component called `Form` (which is a submission form), and I want to pass `props` to it so I can add the inputs, selects, buttons depending on the `props` object. Let me know if I was not clear, comming from React world and very curious about Vue.js!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> A prop is a custom attribute for passing information from parent components. A child component needs to explicitly declare the props it expects to receive using the props option:

In your case, parent component:

```
<template>
  <child :title-data="sample_data"></child>
</template>
```

You can set the data in 'sample_data' in parent component.

```
data: function () {
  return {
    sample_data: {
      'title': '',
      'subtitle': ''
    }
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <span> {{ titleData.title }} </span>
  <span> {{ titleData.subtitle }} </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'child',
  props: ['titleData']
}
</script>
```

Yes, you have to declare the props inside the component. You can declare it in the above way or you can be more explicit about the props thus validating the props. Read this on how to go about it: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation

Also read about kebab-case vs camelCase in props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Read more about props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question! I see `:title-data` only once, should that not be the property name I use inside the `child` component? becase `title-data` is not a reserved word with speciall funcionality right?

Comment: It is the prop declared inside the child, see props: ['titleData'], look at this to understand the change of case: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Comment: Basically if your prop is 'titleData' (camelCase), then when you use it in an html as an attribute it has to be used as 'title-data' (kebab-case).

Comment: I think so, there is one thing I am not sure, but guess I'll add a new question with that. Thank you!